# SystemJS: The YouTube API external JS library mistaken for local TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, youtube-api, systemjs, youtube-javascript-api

Training my TypeScript and Angular skills. First by converting [my simple HTML website](https://pendrokar.github.io/magia-ts/)'s two scripts to **JUST** TypeScript for now. I was able to convert the Scroller script, but am having problems with YouTube API as it is an remote external JS file and not a SystemJS module.

I failed to have the API trigger a module's function after it has loaded. So [here](https://stackoverrun.com/ru/q/11789890) I found out that using 'await import' is supposedly the way to go, but it isn't working out.

```js
SystemJS.config({
  map: {
 youtube: "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"
  },
  meta: {
 "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api": {
   "format": "global",
   "exports": "youtube",
   "scriptLoad": true,
   "build": false
 }
  }
});

...

export default class YouTubeService {
async loadAPI() {

 try {
  await import('youtube'); // automatically injects a script tag
  console.log('API loaded');
 }
 catch (e) {
  console.error('The YouTube API failed to load');
 }
```

TypeScript throws the following error:

> /js/main.ts [1 errors] (48, 17) File
>   '/var/www/magia-ts/node_modules/@types/youtube/index.d.ts' is not a
>   module.

Original source code: https://github.com/Pendrokar/magia-ts/blob/7677f0ad1e2219ac041e3a8177561c36e905c3c3/js/main.ts#L48

Comment: "declare var youtube : string;" and replacing the string compiles, but then the await throws an error: 'youtube is not defined' meaning the config is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the YouTube API was originally designed to be loaded globally, `@types/youtube` describes the global `YT` variable that it defines.  The `youtube` virtual module that you have configured with SystemJS and are trying to import is not declared anywhere for TypeScript.  Since the name matches, TypeScript is looking for a declaration of the `youtube` module in `@types/youtube`, but it isn't there.  You'll need to add a declaration that simply indicates that the `youtube` module is the same as the `YT` global variable declared by `@types/youtube`.  Create a new file `declaration.d.ts` containing:

```
declare module "youtube" {
    export = YT;
}
```

and the TypeScript error should go away.

As an aside, shouldn't the `exports` in the SystemJS configuration entry be `YT`, not `youtube`?

Comment: Making the declaration worked, but it is still ignoring the SystemJS config, see the updated Source Code link. I take it it doesn't matter if I use 'System'. or 'SystemJS,'.

As then I face the error: _'The YouTube API failed to load: TypeError: context_1.import is not a function'_

Comment: Right, it looks like SystemJS 0.21 doesn't support dynamic import.  You'd have to move to SystemJS 2.0 (which requires a bunch of other configuration changes) or find a different solution. :(

Comment: No wait, I think I succeeded by using 0.21.5 instead of 0.19.22.

Comment: Yep, it seems to work fine once a declaration file is made and the latest version of SystemJS is used. 2.0 is too new for me to try right now.

Thank you for your time Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Of course the supposedly unclean method of injecting the script works:

```js
try {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (firstScriptTag.parentNode != null) {
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  }

  // await import(youtube); // automatically injects a script tag
  console.log('API loaded');
} catch (e) {
  console.error('The YouTube API failed to load: ' + e);
}
```